# Use XSLT to convert delimited text to XML

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have some double pipe delimited data inside some XML tags and I would like to replace/convert the delimited text to XML.
The delimited text also uses a colon to separate the heading and the data, like so: ||tagname:data||
The headings or tag names could be anything, this is just one example. So I don't know in advance what I'm getting. I must take what's listed in front of the colon and use that.

```
 <doc>
      <arr name="content">
      <str>  stream_source_info docname   stream_content_type text/html   stream_size 412   Content-Encoding ISO-8859-1   stream_name docname   Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1   resourceName docname       ||phone:3282||email:Lori.KS@.edu||officenumber:D-107A||vcard:https://c3qa/profiles/vcard/profile.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b||photo:https://c3qa/profiles/photo.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846||pronunciation:https://c3qa/profiles/audio.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846||  </str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

Can I use XSLT to transform this XML into this?

```
 <doc>
      <arr name="content">
      <str>  stream_source_info docname   stream_content_type text/html   stream_size 412   Content-Encoding ISO-8859-1   stream_name docname   Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1   resourceName docname  
          <phone>3282</phone>
          <email>Lori.KS@.edu</email>
          <officenumber>D-107A</officenumber>
          <vcard>https://c3qa/profiles/vcard/profile.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b</vcard>
          <photo>https://c3qa/profiles/photo.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846</photo>
          <pronunciation>https://c3qa/profiles/audio.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846</pronunciation>
      </str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

The URLs will have to be wrapped in CDATA and the delimited version will have to be replaced.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`analyze-string` can help, with Saxon 9.5 the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="str">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\|((\|[^|]+\|)+)\|">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="regex-group(1)" regex="\|(\w+):([^|]+)\|">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<doc>
      <arr name="content">
      <str>  stream_source_info docname   stream_content_type text/html   stream_size 412   Content-Encoding ISO-8859-1   stream_name docname   Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1   resourceName docname       ||phone:3282||email:Lori.KS@.edu||officenumber:D-107A||vcard:https://c3qa/profiles/vcard/profile.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b||photo:https://c3qa/profiles/photo.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846||pronunciation:https://c3qa/profiles/audio.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846||  </str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

into the result

```
<doc>
      <arr name="content">
      <str>  stream_source_info docname   stream_content_type text/html   stream_size 412   Content-Encoding ISO-8859-1   stream_name docname   Content-Type text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1   resourceName docname       <phone>3282</phone>
         <email>Lori.KS@.edu</email>
         <officenumber>D-107A</officenumber>
         <vcard>https://c3qa/profiles/vcard/profile.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b</vcard>
         <photo>https://c3qa/profiles/photo.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846</photo>
         <pronunciation>https://c3qa/profiles/audio.do?key=5c28d263-d8aa-4a8a-ae90-4e8b13de7a0b&amp;lastMod=1348674215846</pronunciation>  
      </str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

Comment: +1! Outstanding! Thanks, that worked beautifully! I had to play around with Saxon command line but I got it working.

Comment: Hi Martin, my XML changed and sometimes the str has a name i.e. <str name="id"> how do I preserve the name too?

Comment: Ok, I changed the match="str" to match="str/@type" and that seems to have worked. Is that right?

Comment: Hi Martin, adding str/@type preserves the type but doesn't parse the text. How do I fix this?

Comment: If there are attributes on the `str` element you want to preserve then use `<xsl:template match="str">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\|((\|[^|]+\|)+)\|">...</xsl:analyze-string></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm so sorry but the xslt stopped working for some reason. I posted a new question. If you have time could you take a look?