# Saxon9HE error XLM0001: Too many nested apply-templates calls. The stylesheet may be looping

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using Saxon9HE to transform some XML 2.0. from a Java class; the solution is from this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996969/how-do-i-fix-this-xslt-that-stopped-working)
I'm transforming double pipe delimited text into XML.
However, some of the fields contain people's resumes and the transform throws the looping error mentioned in the title.

Is there a way fix this?
I read about increasing the maximum depth in templates stack but that only applies to Oxygen; is there a similar setting in the Saxon9HE.jar?

Here's the code, you can also click on the link above to get the code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="str">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\|((\|\s*[^|]+\s*\|)+)\|">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="regex-group(1)" regex="\|\s*(\w+):([^|]+?)\s*\|">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you use Oracle´s Java then read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html, it suggests you can increase the stack space using the `-Xss` command line option of `java.exe` you run your Java code with.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the OP is triggering that. I think that if he hit the Java stack limit, Saxon would be crashing - it wouldn't get a chance to complain about apply-templates?

Comment: I spent an hour googling and reading Saxon docs, but I couldn't find the solution for you. Might be easier to ask the Oxygen community.

Comment: @Vadi, Saxon traps the StackOverflow exception and attempts to explain it in terms of the stylesheet code that was being executed.

Comment: @Vadi; I'm not using Oxygen, that's just where I found a suggestion to  expand the stack memory. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities: either the stylesheet is doing infinite recursion, or it is doing deep recursion that would terminate eventually, but requires too much stack space.

The first step is to find out which of these applies, and we can't do that without seeing your code.

If it's non-terminating recursion then obviously that's a bug in your code that needs to be fixed.

If it's deep but finite recursion, then there may be a solution by increasing the resources available, but it depends how close to the limit you are. As a practical rule-of-thumb, don't attempt a recursion that goes more than about 500 levels deep.

There are a number of ways of rewriting the code to avoid deep recursion:

(a) you may be able to take advantage of Saxon's tail-call optimization

(b) you may be able to use a divide-and-conquer recursive algorithm in place of head-tail recursion

(c) you may be able to avoid recursion altogether, for example by using xsl:iterate or xsl:analyze-string or the fold-left() function.

But we can't help much further without seeing what you are trying to do. Show us the code!

Comment: You can get the code by clicking the link to the prior question and I've added the code for completeness.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess then it's probably not recursion at the application level causing the problem, but recursion within the regex engine. The way to reduce that is to try to write the regex in a way that avoids the need for backtracking. For example in the second regex, the fragment `([^|]+?)\s*` could possibly be rewritten as `([^|\s]+?)\s*`.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. I get the same error; Error at xsl:apply-templates on line 7 of dbl-pipe.xsl:
  SXLM0001: Too many nested apply-templates calls. The stylesheet may be looping.

Comment: If you've got a stylesheet and source doc that demonstrate the problem then post them at saxonica.plan.io and we'll see if we can work out what's going on and make suggestions.

Comment: I created issue #1859